# HoloLens device not able to connect to internet

Tags: hololens

We have a corporate wifi, connected a new hololens virtual reality device using root & intermediate certificates installed in hololens device of wifi and it got connected and has an ip address. But from our core switch not able to ping hololens ip and from hololens we don't view any command prompt for testing purposes.Confused how to tshoot the same.

Answer (score 0):

The HoloLens2 does **not** respond to pings over WiFi or ethernet adapter.

I have verified this by enabling the device portal and pinging the IP of several different HoloLens 2.   There is no way to enable response to ICMP for HL2 as far as I know.

However, you **can** say, "What is my IP" and then the HoloLens 2 should show you the exact IP address that it has in its network adapter.

[Device Portal accessible via https port 443 after enabled from settings>update>for developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vanmf.png)